# Doubt concerning biot savarts law

Tags: electromagnetism

Why do we calculate $dB$ for an infinitesimal part of a wire instead of a point?What is the reason behind that?Why can't we determine the magnetic field of a point with respect to a point of the wire instead of an infinitesimal part?

Also why is $dB$ proportional to $dl$ where $dl$ is the infinitesimal length of the wire?An infinitesimal quantity doesn't have any definite value,so how can we increase or decrease $dl$ for $dB$ to be proportional to it?Please give an intuitive explanation since it's really bothering me.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of integrals through Riemann sums? If not, I recommend looking it up. Also, there are no "points" in physics. A "point" of the wire does not give rise to any fields. A small, finite part does.

Comment: A moving point charge give rise to an electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

A point cannot produce any magnetic field, it should have some length for it to produce any field.

Now coming to the second question. As pointed out by @Angry Refrigerator in their answer, dlXr shows the direction of the magnetic field, while I and distance from wire show its magnitude. It is **not** correct to say dB is proportional to dL. As you rightly thought, adding something to an infinitesimal number isnt correct and it is better for u to not think of it in that way. Maybe you can think of it qualitatively where length of wire doubled then mag. field double keeping everything same. But @Angry Refrigerator's interpretation is correct and think of it in that way.

Comment: But isn't $dl$ unfixed?How can you double it's length?

Comment: @AritraBarua My initial answer was incorrect, please check the edited version and hopefully your doubt is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @Lili FN in the comments, "points" of a wire do not give rise to a magnetic field. But a small length of wire does.
This makes sense intuitively since it's actually the current (density) $\vec{j}(\vec{r})$ that gives rise to a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ (Ampere's Law).
And in the $1d$ case (infinitely thin wire), integrating over the direction of the current, or integrating over small bits of the wire $\mathrm{d}\vec{l}$ is equivalent.

Looking at the whole equation makes it easier to see why "$\mathrm{d}{B}$ is proportional to $\mathrm{d}{l}$". In the Biot-Savart law you're really integrating over the current at a given position $I(\vec{r})$. The $\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{l} \times \vec{r}}{|r|^3}$ bit of the integral is just giving you a direction for the magnetic field $d\vec{B}$, while it's amplitude is dictated by $I(\vec{r})$. Just as Ampere's law hints at.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but if a point doesn't give rise to a magnetic field,why can't we then deal with the whole wire instead of small portions?I mean both have lengths,so why does small or the whole wire matter here?Can't we just find out the magnetic field for the whole wire directly?What computations issue will occur in that case?

Comment: The strength of the magnetic field coming from a small bit of wire is $B \sim I(r)/r$, where $r$ is the distance to the small bit of wire and I(r) is the current at that place.
But what if the wire is a weird shape, say in the shape of the letter "U"? Then you need to sum up, i.e. integrate over all the small bits of wire which make up the letter "U".
That's the real content of the Biot-Savart law! It tells you that, knowing that $B \sim I(r)/r$, that you can get the full magnetic field by dividing a wire into small pieces (of size $dl$ for which your can apply the relation $B \sim I(r)/r$.